# Under flex-layout, help-text with container is not aligned on screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, bootstrap-4

In this particular sample all input boxes shall align in same base line, even if they are provided with varied `help-text`. On all the container `mt-auto` is applied, however with or without `help-text` it is not aligned in `flex` layout.

[image: misaligned fields]

```
<html>
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="form-row d-flex">
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-4 mt-auto">
        <label for="validationServer03">City</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control is-invalid" id="validationServer03" placeholder="City" required>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          Please provide a valid city.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-4 mt-auto">
        <label for="validationServer04">State</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control is-invalid" id="validationServer04" placeholder="State" required>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-4  mt-auto">
        <label for="validationServer05">Zip</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control is-invalid" id="validationServer05" placeholder="Zip" required>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          Please provide a valid zip.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
</html>
```

I'm using:

- Bootstrap 4.1
- Google Chrome (67.0.3396.99 (Official Build) (64-bit))
- Windows 7 OS.

Please find the test case on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vipbhavsar/aq9Laaew/98073/